# Confusion about Velocity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I understand that velocity is a vector that has a direction and magnitude. For example, **v**(t) = m • < a,b,c >.
What I am not grasping is when people say velocity is for example, 500 ft/sec. 
How do you change from a vector to an actual value like 500 ft/sec?

Is the number 500 ft/second perhaps the magnitude of a vector? That is my guess but I am unsure.

Comment: When they say it has velocity 500 ft/sec, they are just stating the magnitude of the vector, and not the direction. There should also be a direction.

Comment: Okay thank you so much! So they would say, "500 ft/sec in the north direction?

Comment: Would be one possibility.  Its certainly easier to talk about velocity in euclidean space rather than spherical space.  As for *how* to find the magnitude of a vector, there are many different concepts of "magnitude" or "norm."  The most common of which is the [euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) and this is the one generally used in every day conversation, but you know mathematicians like to generalize concepts and this is not the only interesting norm to us.

Comment: Speed is technical term for magnitude of velocity vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change a vector to an actual value.

Imagine that you are in a car with a velocity of 100 km/h moving to the south,
in that moment you can change the car for a vector with a magnitud of 100 km/h looking to the south.

In the moment that you are getting slower the length of the vector gets shorter.

Comment: "the 'longitude' of the vector gets shorter"  I do not think the word longitude means what you think it does.

Comment: i wanted to mean the lenght, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

Every vector $\vec{\mathrm{A}}$ has a magnitude $\lvert\vec{\mathrm{A}}\rvert$.
That is what is referred to, when people say the velocity is $50\, \mathrm{ft/s}$.
 Actually they want to say that the magnitude of the velocity vector is $50\, \mathrm{ft/s}$.

Comment: Yes, they should say "speed," and not "velocity."